# Bootstrap Responsive Image Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive-images

I want to create a responsive image grid with Bootstrap. I have 4 images and I need 1x4 grid for desktop size and 2x2 grid for mobile size. I tried the following code, but there are unnecessary blanks between images for desktop size. Also there isn't any space for mobile size. How can I adjust this layout?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The columns in bootstrap have padding on them.
I would add a class to your `<div class="row">` and remove the padding to the columns via css.

Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row imagetiles">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.scdn.co/image/2fd8fa0f7ef2f83691a0fb9628ee369b8e3b688e class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <style>
  div.imagetiles div.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-3.col-xs-6{
  padding: 0px;
}
    </style>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24437/)

That takes care of the space on desktop.
You can adjust this space between the images by adjusting the padding on the columns via CSS. For mobile devices - just use media queries. Bootstrap has the following queries:

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Example:

```
    @media(max-width: 480px){
div.imagetiles div.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-3.col-xs-6{
      padding: 5px;}
}
```

Comment: For some images, the alignment isn't working. How can I fix this? You can see an example here; https://jsfiddle.net/ovuncuzun/u65qx59w/1/

Comment: It's because The Godfather image is a different size then the other 3 images. The Godfather image is 640px by 634px, while the other 3 are 640px by 640px.

Comment: These images are coming randomly. Can I change all images as 640px by 640px although they aren't on runtime? I am using AngularJS. Thanks

Comment: I suggest asking a new question on this site describing what your new problem is!